# Date in JLabel (Java bean)

Tags: java, swing, date, jlabel

I trying to implement current date using get set method in Java. It's a Java bean, and I should be able to get the date when I import in the GUI. My problem is it doesn't show the current date, it just shows the Jlabel text.

Below is my code:

```
package datebean;

import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * A JavaBean for displaying dates.
 */
public class DateBean extends JPanel {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    JLabel lblDay = new JLabel("dd"),
            lblMonth = new JLabel("mm"),
            lblYear = new JLabel("yy");

    public DateBean() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());
        this.add(lblDay);
        this.add(lblMonth);
        this.add(lblYear);
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        day = dateFormat.format(date);
        lblDay.setText(day);
    }

    public String getDay(String day){
        return day;
    }

    public void setMonth(String month) {
        month = dateFormat.format(date);
        lblMonth.setText(month);
    }

    public String getMonth(String month){
        return month;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        year = dateFormat.format(date);
        lblYear.setText(year);
    }

    public String getYear(String year){
        return year;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating some crazy self-formating label, you could just use the new `java.time.LocalTime` Class (added in Java8) for logic/calculating purposes and a normal `JLable` for the graphical part.

Anyway, here is an example based on your concept:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class DateLabel extends JLabel {
    private LocalDate           date;
    private DateTimeFormatter   dtf;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param day      The day of the date
     * @param month    The month of the date
     * @param year     The year of the date
     * @param pattern  The format of the date
     */
    public DateLabel(final int day, final int month, final int year, final String pattern) {
        date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
        dtf  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
        redraw();
    }

    public final int getDay()   {return date.getDayOfMonth();}
    public final int getMonth() {return date.getMonthValue();}
    public final int getYear()  {return date.getYear();}

    public final void setDay(final int value) {
        date = LocalDate.of(date.getYear(), date.getMonthValue(), value);
        redraw();
    }

    public final void setMonth(final int value) {
        date = LocalDate.of(date.getYear(), value, date.getDayOfMonth());
        redraw();
    }

    public final void setYear(final int value) {
        date = LocalDate.of(value, date.getMonthValue(), date.getDayOfMonth());
        redraw();
    }

    private final void redraw() {
        super.setText(date.format(dtf));
    }
    /**
     * Method is deprecated, please use {@link #setDay(int)}, {@link #setMonth(int)},
     * and {@link #setYear(int)} instead
     * @param text
     */
    @Deprecated
    public final void setText(final String text) {
        super.setText(text);
    }

}
```

And an example usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame wnd = new JFrame("DateLabel Test");
    wnd.setLocation(200, 200);
    wnd.setSize(300, 300);
    wnd.setLayout(null);
    wnd.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    DateLabel lblDate1 = new DateLabel(24, 12, 2014, "dd.MM.yyyy");
    lblDate1.setLocation(10, 10);
    lblDate1.setSize(100, 15);
    wnd.add(lblDate1);

    DateLabel lblDate2 = new DateLabel(24, 12, 2014, "MM/dd/yyyy");
    lblDate2.setLocation(10, 30);
    lblDate2.setSize(100, 15);
    wnd.add(lblDate2);

    wnd.setVisible(true);

    lblDate2.setDay(lblDate1.getDay() + 7);
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply. When I import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter; 
why does it says package not found ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my posting above, this package was added in Java8 (jdk 1.8.0). Maybe you have an older jdk (and jre) installed on your system?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't concentrating.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you do not know, what you want to do...

You can start with adding

```
setDay(null);
```

to your constructor, to see some change (probably not the one you want).